# pam_mkhomedir.so does not create home directories on CentOs?

Tags: linux, centos, ldap, centos7, pam

I'm configuring a linux cluster (CentOS 7.2) and I'm trying to login against LDAP.

My LDAP server is configured and runs correctly, both LDAP users and groups appear when I get the list throw getent passwd / getent group, and logins are possible by SSH with LDAP users. **id** *ldapuser* returns the expected *ldapuser* information.

My problem is when I do login, the home directory is not created. 
I edited the file /etc/pam.d/system-auth to add the following line:

```
session     required      pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022
```

but no success. I tried to restart nslcd, the O.S, ... , but nothing worked.

I can't see what I am missing...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I executed `authconfig --enablemkhomedir --update` on each machine and it worked